# Convert sheetpathrange string to list value of range

Tags: excel, vba

I'm interacting one Excel file to another which contains macros. While getting data from macros Excel the `range("A3").validation.formula1` gives sometime path instead of list values separated by `;` as `=Sheet1!$A13:$B13`.

How to get those value as list i.e. whatever value added in `A13` to `B13` shall be available in a list or string.

Answer (score 1):

Using

```
Dim ListArray As Variant
ListArray = Evaluate("=Sheet1!$A13:$B13").Value
```

or in your case probably

```
ListArray = Evaluate(Range("A3").Validation.Formula1).Value
```

will return the values of range `A13:B13` in `Sheet1` as 2 dimensional array that you can access like:

```
ListArray(row, column)
```

so for example

```
ListArray(1, 1)   ' value of A13
ListArray(1, 2)   ' value of B13
```